# Date checker with error check

Tags: php, date

Here is some thing am looking for.

1. I need a date picker for `start_date` and `end_date`.
2. When user makes an wrong entry it should give some error. (eg: start_date: `27/11/2013` and end_date: `29/11/2013`) and return to the same page.

My trials goes like this.

1. Created a `jumpMenus` for day, month, and year.
2. used `strtotime()` to find the difference.
3. If less than `0` store generate error flag and return to current page.

But that didn't work. (I didn't include the code because I want something better and I know it is not the right way.)

Can anyone guide me on how to create a work around?

This is what I have tried only years: 
Html form:

```
       <label>Trip Start date</label>
             <select name="day" id="tripStart" onchange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
                  <option>01</option>
                  .
                  <option>31</option>
             </select>
             <select name="month">
                  <option>Jan</option>
                   .
                   .
                   <option>Dec</option>
              </select>
              <select name="year">
                   <option>2013</option>
                   .
                   .
                   <option>2024</option>
              </select>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td width="315"><label>Trip End date</label>
              <select name="day2" onchange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
                    <option>01</option>
                    .
                    .
                    <option>31</option>
              </select>
              <select name="month2">
                     <option>Jan</option>
                     .
                     .
                     <option>Dec</option>
              </select>
              <select name="year2">
                      <option>2013</option>
                    .
                    .
                    <option>2024</option>
              </select>
   </td>
   </tr>

    <?php 
       if( isset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && is_array($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) &&    count($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) >0 )  {
        echo '<ul class="err">';
        foreach($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] as $msg) {
            echo '<li>',$msg,'</li>'; 
            }
        echo '</ul>';
        unset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']);
        }
     ?>
```

in verify.php

```
   $y_start = $_POST['year'];
   $y_end = $_POST['year2'];

     $diff = (strtotime($y_start) - strtotime($y_end ));
     $years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));

         if ($year < 0) {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Please enter a valid year!';
        $errflag = true;
          }

         if($errflag){
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        session_write_close();
        header("location: /application/home.php");
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: Post code so we can see what you were trying to do... It's hard to see what exactly you are asking for... you never said why it didn't work or anything about the errors you received.

Comment: When I submit the form it generates php. but no error it is showing. I need to generate error on the form in home page if user enters a future date as start date.

Comment: Try my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=='check' 
    && isset($_POST['fday']) && isset($_POST['tday']) 
    && isset($_POST['fmonth']) && isset($_POST['tmonth']) 
    && isset($_POST['fyear']) && isset($_POST['tyear']) 
    && ctype_digit($_POST['fday']) && ctype_digit($_POST['tday']) 
    && ctype_digit($_POST['fmonth']) && ctype_digit($_POST['tmonth']) 
    && ctype_digit($_POST['fyear']) && ctype_digit($_POST['tyear'])
){

    $error = 0;

    $fday = sprintf("%02s", $_POST['fday']);
    $fmonth = sprintf("%02s", $_POST['fmonth']);
    $fyear = $_POST['fyear'];
    $fdate = $fday.'/'.$fmonth.'/'.$fyear;

    $tday = sprintf("%02s", $_POST['tday']);
    $tmonth = sprintf("%02s", $_POST['tmonth']);
    $tyear = $_POST['tyear'];
    $tdate = $tday.'/'.$tmonth.'/'.$tyear;

    if(!checkdate($_POST['fmonth'], $_POST['fday'], $_POST['fyear'])){
        $err_startdate = 1;
        $error = 1;
    }
    if(!checkdate($_POST['tmonth'], $_POST['tday'], $_POST['tyear'])){
        $err_enddate = 1;
        $error = 1;
    }



    $format = "d/m/Y";
    $from_date  = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $fdate);
    $to_date  = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $tdate);

    if($from_date > $to_date){
        $err_compare = 1;
        $error = 1;
    }

    if($from_date == $to_date){
        $err_equal = 1;
        $error = 1;
    }

    if(isset($error) && $error == 1){
        if(isset($err_startdate))
        echo '<h1 style="color:lightcoral;">Your starting date is invalid</h1>';
        if(isset($err_enddate))
        echo '<h1 style="color:lightcoral;">Your ending date is invalid</h1>';
        if(isset($err_compare))
        echo '<h1 style="color:lightcoral;">Your starting date is after your ending date</h1>';
        if(isset($err_equal))
        echo '<h1 style="color:lightcoral;">Your starting date is equal to the ending date</h1>';

    }else {

        echo '<h1 style="color:lightgreen;">Success!</h1>';
        echo 'Execute query here with from date: '.$fdate.' and to date: '.$tdate.'<br><br>';
    }
}

if(!isset($error) || $error == 1){

?>


<form method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="check">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
        From Date:
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="3">
        To Date:
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <label for="fmonth" style='font-size: 1.2em;'>Month</label><br>
        <select name="fmonth" id="month">
            <?php
            for($index = 1; $index <= 12; $index++){
            echo '<option';

            if(isset($_POST['fmonth'])){
                if($index == $_POST['fmonth'])
                echo ' selected >';
                else
                echo '>';
            }else{
                if($index == date('m'))
                echo ' selected >';
                else
                echo '>';
            }

            echo $index.'</option>';


            }
            ?>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        <label for="fday" style='font-size: 1.2em;'>Day</label><br>
        <select name="fday" id="day">
            <?php
            for($index = 1; $index <= 31; $index++){
            echo '<option';

            if(isset($_POST['fday'])){
                if($index == $_POST['fday'])
                echo ' selected >';
                else
                echo '>';
            }else{
                if($index == date('d'))
                echo ' selected >';
                else
                echo '>';
            }

            echo $index.'</option>';

            }
            ?>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        <label for="fyear" style='font-size: 1.2em;'>Year</label><br/>
        <select name="fyear" id="year">
            <?php
            for($index = 2013; $index <= 2016; $index++){
            echo '<option';

            if(isset($_POST['fyear'])){
                if($index == $_POST['fyear'])
                echo ' selected >';
                else
                echo '>';
            }else{
                if($index == date('Y'))
                echo ' selected >';
                else
                echo '>';
            }

            echo $index.'</option>';

            }
            ?>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td> - </td>
        <td>
        <label for="tmonth" style='font-size: 1.2em;'>Month</label><br/>
        <select name="tmonth" id="tmonth">
            <?php
            for($index = 1; $index <= 12; $index++){
            echo '<option';

            if(isset($_POST['tmonth'])){
                if($index == $_POST['tmonth'])
                echo ' selected >';
                else
                echo '>';
            }else{
                if($index == date('m'))
                echo ' selected >';
                else
                echo '>';
            }

            echo $index.'</option>';


            }
            ?>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        <label for="tday" style='font-size: 1.2em;'>Day</label><br/>
        <select name="tday" id="tday">
            <?php
            for($index = 1; $index <= 31; $index++){
            echo '<option';

            if(isset($_POST['tday'])){
                if($index == $_POST['tday'])
                echo ' selected >';
                else
                echo '>';
            }else{
                if($index == date('d'))
                echo ' selected >';
                else
                echo '>';
            }

            echo $index.'</option>';

            }
            ?>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        <label for="tyear" style='font-size: 1.2em;'>Year</label><br/>
        <select name="tyear" id="tyear">
            <?php
            for($index = 2013; $index <= 2016; $index++){
            echo '<option';

            if(isset($_POST['tyear'])){
                if($index == $_POST['tyear'])
                echo ' selected >';
                else
                echo '>';
            }else{
                if($index == date('Y'))
                echo ' selected >';
                else
                echo '>';
            }

            echo $index.'</option>';

            }
            ?>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Mana and Arian, However I am looking for something like a form where user makes the start of a trip and end of a trip to store the same in pdf and db.

Comment: @user2947210 I updated my answer, It should work, you need to fill in your own DB Query... but it should work fine, I didn't format the styling, but I did put it in a table.

Comment: Arian it works with no attribute in my php page. However if I put an attribute to generate pdf using fpdf; it echoes no error message. I believe I made mistake in placing your code. Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 5.2.2, DateTime objects can be compared using [comparison operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php#97810).

```
<?php
$date1 = new DateTime("now");
$date2 = new DateTime("tomorrow");

var_dump($date1 == $date2);
var_dump($date1 < $date2);
var_dump($date1 > $date2);
?>
```

This method is good for comparison but if you are interested in actual time difference in days or hours use [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php#97810) code by Dennis C on php Manual.

```
<?php
function date_diff($date1, $date2) {
    $current = $date1;
    $datetime2 = date_create($date2);
    $count = 0;
    while(date_create($current) < $datetime2){
        $current = gmdate("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($current)));
        $count++;
    }
    return $count;
}

echo (date_diff('2010-3-9', '2011-4-10')." days <br \>");
?>
```